# Syntax check cfengine files before updating git repository

Tags: git, gitolite, cfengine

I have my cfengine (2 and 3) files in a git repository fronted by gitolite.

Users of this repo have a pre-commit hook that will perform syntax/promise checks on the files as needed.  *This works fine*.

To protect against someone not having the pre-commit hook, I would like to add a hook in the bare repository on the gitolite server.  I know I need to use a pre-receive or update.secondary hook.  Beyond that, I'm stumped.

I've found a number of sites with instructions on doing this with PHP fies, but those can be checked individually, but to my (admittedly limited) understanding of cfengine I need all the cfengine files before I can check them.

Short of having the hook clone the repo, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, at the moment you need to have all your CFEngine files available to check them, since you will get a failure if, for example, some needed file is not present or if no bundlesequence is defined, regardless of whether the file syntax is correct.

Given this, I think you would need to clone the repo in the server. Once the repo is cloned, you could have your hook just update it, to reduce performance impact.

Comment: And to note, you should use the `update` hook, not the `pre-receive`.  The update will run for each individual branch, which is what you want.